# Statistical mean of polygon areas in a landscape

Tags: netlogo

I have a landscape with polygons composed of several patches.

[image]

The polygons are numbered from 1 to 80. I calculated the polygon area (in ha) as follows :

```
to calculate-polygon-area 
let patch-area 0.01 ;; one patch = 0.01 ha 
let list-ID-polygon ( [plabel] of patches )
set list-ID-polygon remove-duplicates list-ID-polygon
set list-ID-polygon remove "" list-ID-polygon 

foreach list-ID-polygon [ 
ask patches with [plabel = ?] [ 
  set polygon-area count patches with [plabel = ?] * patch-area ] ] 
end
```

I would like to calculate the statistical mean of polygon areas in my landscape. How can I define the list with the area of each unique polygon because

```
mean [polygon-area] of patches
```

gives the mean of areas by patch ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going through the patches, you can just get it from the polygon ids. To do so, you can use `map` to return the area of each polygon, and then just use `mean` on that:

`mean map [ count patches with [ plabel = ? ] * patch-area ] list-ID-polygon`